# FBSessionLoginBehaviorWithNoFallbackToWebView opens safari if no app is installed

Tags: ios, facebook, uiwebview, safari, facebook-oauth

I want to log the user into my app with Facebook using (in this order) these methods:

1. The account stored in settings (via the Accounts Framework)
2. Switching to the Facebook App
3. Displaying my own UIWebView inside the app (and sending the requests
       manually)

If one method doesn't work, I want to fallback to the next.

The problem I'm having is that

```
[self.fbsession openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView 
               completionHandler:
```

opens Safari or shows a popup that I can't customise.

I absolutely need to follow this order because I use a webview for other social networks (ie Twitter, LinkedIn and GooglePlus).

Is there any way to manually open the Facebook App for the Oauth flow ?

Comment: As of Oct 2, 2013, "Native iOS and Android apps must not use their own web views for Facebook Login". See https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/

Comment: hmm... thanks for the link, I had no idea of that. But I think I got that covered since I let them use the account on the device,and the facebook app. But if they don't have neither (because they live under a rock), can I use my own web view ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer to that is still no. This is about providing a consistent experience to Facebook users across all apps. If apps decide to use their own webview with decorations, then it degrades user trust, and makes them more vulnerable to future social engineering hacks.

Comment: So then the preferred method would be to open Safari if the user doesn't have the Facebook app ?

Comment: The preferred method is to allow the Facebook SDK handle the fallback logic.

Answer (score 0):

To manually check if the Facebook app is installed you can use:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://requests"]]
```